# Python - Performance difference between importing a function and locally declaring it?

Tags: python, performance, runtime

Is there a significant difference in performance between importing a function versus declaring it in the current file in Python?

I have a small function (one-liner) that I use often in several *.py* files in my program. I wish to instead define it once so that changes I make to it are reflected everywhere. However, I am not sure whether using it as an imported function will add additional overhead when calling it...

Comment: No extra overhead in the call.  But really, who cares? We don't use Python to be super machine efficient.  We use it to be programmer efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jet Blue for better understanding go with the [python wiki PerformanceTips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)

> import statements can be executed just about anywhere. It's often useful to place them inside functions to restrict their visibility and/or reduce initial startup time. Although Python's interpreter is optimized to not import the same module multiple times, repeatedly executing an import statement can seriously affect performance in some circumstances.
>
> Consider the following two snippets of code (originally from Greg McFarlane, I believe - I found it unattributed in a comp.lang.python python-list@python.org posting and later attributed to him in another source):

```
def doit1():
    import string ###### import statement inside function
    string.lower('Python')

for num in range(100000):
    doit1()
```

> or:

```
import string ###### import statement outside function
def doit2():
    string.lower('Python')

for num in range(100000):
    doit2()
```

> doit2 will run much faster than doit1, even though the reference to the string module is global in doit2. Here's a Python interpreter session run using Python 2.3 and the new timeit module, which shows how much faster the second is than the first:

```
def doit1():
    import string
    string.lower('Python')

import string
def doit2():
    string.lower('Python')

import timeit
t = timeit.Timer(setup='from __main__ import doit1', stmt='doit1()')
t.timeit()
11.479144930839539
t = timeit.Timer(setup='from __main__ import doit2', stmt='doit2()')
t.timeit()
4.6661689281463623
```

> String methods were introduced to the language in Python 2.0. These provide a version that avoids the import completely and runs even faster:

```
def doit3():
    'Python'.lower()

for num in range(100000):
    doit3()
```

> Here's the proof from timeit:

def doit3():
    'Python'.lower()

t = timeit.Timer(setup='from **main** import doit3', stmt='doit3()')
t.timeit()
2.5606080293655396

> The above example is obviously a bit contrived, but the general principle holds.
>
> Note that putting an import in a function can speed up the initial loading of the module, especially if the imported module might not be required. This is generally a case of a "lazy" optimization -- avoiding work (importing a module, which can be very expensive) until you are sure it is required.
>
> This is only a significant saving in cases where the module wouldn't have been imported at all (from any module) -- if the module is already loaded (as will be the case for many standard modules, like string or re), avoiding an import doesn't save you anything. To see what modules are loaded in the system look in sys.modules.
>
> A good way to do lazy imports is:

```
email = None

def parse_email():
    global email
    if email is None:
        import email
```

> This way the email module will only be imported once, on the first invocation of parse_email().

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there should be a difference between a call to a function locally declared vs a function which is imported. Although, there is a small difference between a line of code being executed vs a function called for the same code to be executed. [This](https://www.pythoncentral.io/time-a-python-function/) should help in case I was a bit confusing with my wording.